# Resque not failing an obviously buggy job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, job-scheduling, resque

I have the following problem with Resque and Rails 6 (ruby 2.7.2). I am new to this gem and wanted to do some simple testing to see how things are handled, so I created a simple failing job:

```
class TestJob < ApplicationJob
  @queue = :default

  def self.perform(*args)
    0/0
  end
end
```

Obviously, when I go to the console and run it, I get the error:

```
irb(main):001:0> TestJob.perform
Traceback (most recent call last):
        3: from (irb):1
        2: from app/jobs/test_job.rb:5:in `perform'
        1: from app/jobs/test_job.rb:5:in `/'
ZeroDivisionError (divided by 0)
```

But when I run my worker with the command:

```
QUEUE=* VVERBOSE=true rake resque:work
```

And then enqueue my job in rails console, the output I get is:

```
irb(main):002:0> Resque.enqueue(TestJob)
=> true
```

And in the resque logs:

```
** [21:32:57 2020-12-09] 15198: resque-2.0.0: Waiting for default
** [21:33:02 2020-12-09] 15198: Checking default
** [21:33:02 2020-12-09] 15198: Found job on default
** [21:33:02 2020-12-09] 15198: resque-2.0.0: Processing default since 1607545982 [TestJob]
** [21:33:02 2020-12-09] 15198: got: (Job{default} | TestJob | [])
** [21:33:02 2020-12-09] 15198: resque-2.0.0: Forked 15765 at 1607545982
** [21:33:02 2020-12-09] 15765: done: (Job{default} | TestJob | [])
```

Additionally, in the resque web UI it counts this process as successful. The number of failed jobs stays 0. Furthermore, any `puts` and `raise` I put into the `perform` method are not showing in resque/rails console logs.

I have done a basic resque setup on a fresh rails app following the README on the resque's github page. I did not do anything custom. Obviously I restarted my console and worker after I made changes to the `test_job.rb` file, so this is not a problem of loading (maybe?). I also tried changing `self.perform` to `perform`.

Comment: To ensure you're running the right code, make `TestJob.perform` send something to the log.

Comment: @Schwern is there some different way to do that than `puts`? Because I already tried that.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Resque, but [their wiki says](https://github.com/resque/resque/wiki/Logging) you can treat it like a normal [Logger](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/logger/rdoc/Logger.html#method-i-log).

Comment: @Schwern thanks for your interest in helping me. I managed to fix my problem and I posted the answer below. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why, but this is the solution. Rather than running:

```
Resque.enqueue(TestJob)
```

one should run:

```
TestJob.perform_later
```

The thing is, the first way is from the Resque README, and the second one is from the Rails docs. I guess I was fixated on doing this the first way, but it looks like going with the rails conventions is always best.

Comment: The Resque wiki has [special instructions when using ActiveJob](https://github.com/resque/resque/wiki/ActiveJob) which says to use `perform_later`.

Comment: Yeah I missed that. The README shows the `enqueue` way only :/

Comment: That understandable as Resque does not require Rails nor ActiveJob. However, Rails is pretty common. Maybe you can edit [their README](https://github.com/resque/resque/blob/master/README.markdown) to include a mention.

Comment: @Schwern I created a PR as you suggested https://github.com/resque/resque/pull/1735